# Trying to click a button in safari

Tags: applescript, safari

I'm trying to click a button in a webpage with AppleScript, but it only seem to work 1/10 times. I copied this code,

```
to clickID(theId) --creates a function that we can use over and over again instead of writing this code over and over again

tell application "Safari" -- lets AppleScript know what program to controll

    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').click();" in document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').onclick();" in document 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').submit();" in document 1 -- performs JavaScript code that clicks on the element of a specific id

    end tell -- tells Applescript you are done talking to Safari

end clickID -- lets AppleScript know we are done with the function
```

I added in the .onClick() and .submit() lines because I saw them in some other code snippets and figured it might help for backup. But it didn't affect it at all. Is it a weird button or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the actual URL, and which button if more than one?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying [Keyboard Maestro](http://KeyboardMaestro.com).

It has a built-in feature to "Click Safari Link" or "Click Google Chrome Link" and also has a feature to click *buttons* too.

If you can link to an example page, I can give more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you got the code from [this website.](http://www.cubemg.com/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-web-page-with-applescript/)

Did you read the next part of the code:

> Now when you would like to click on something on a web page, lets say
>   its the “More” button on Google,  you can insert this  anywhere in
>   your code.
>
> ```
> clickID("htb_more")
> ```

Comment: Yes, I implemented that line in my code, "clickID("btn btn-primary ng-scope")"

Comment: @MatthewAverill have you read the next part of the code in the next section

Comment: @Matthew HTML element IDs can’t contain spaces. Double check the ID of the element you’re trying to target.